# increment loop the value associate with a key of a dictionary, whithout create a new incremented key

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I want to increment loop the value associate with a key of a dictionary, whithout create a new incremented key, like this one :

code :

```
List_elem = ["D", "V", "D", "D", "D", "V", "D", "V", "V", "V", "V","D","V","V"]
elem_of_list = "D"
dic_list = {}
valeur = 0
for numberResult in range(0, len(List_elem)):
       dic_list[len(dic_list)] = valeur = valeur + 1
       print(dic_list)
```

Here is contained of dictionary after code execution :

```
{0: 1}
{0: 1, 1: 2}
{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}
{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4}
{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5}
{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6}
{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7}
{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8}
{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9}
{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9, 9: 10}
{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9, 9: 10, 10: 11}
{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9, 9: 10, 10: 11, 11: 12}
{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9, 9: 10, 10: 11, 11: 12, 12: 13}
{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9, 9: 10, 10: 11, 11: 12, 12: 13, 13: 14}
>>>
```

But I want it to send me back this dictionary :

```
{0:14}
```

Than only the value associate to the key be increment, here, the value associate to the last key.
While without loop I can incremate normally. For example with this code :

```
dic_list = {1: 3, 2: 6, 3: 9, 4: 12}
valeur = 0
dic_list[len(dic_list)] = valeur = valeur + 1
print(dic_list)
```

I get a dictionary like that :

```
{1: 3, 2: 6, 3: 9, 4: 1}
```

the element associate to the last key has changed of value, from 12 to 1. As I wanted.
How can I do it in a loop ?

Comment: Can you have a example of completeList and withthisResult pls

Comment: It is not clear what the error is. Please see this on How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I get the result list of a team on this site : [link](https://www.flashscore.fr/equipe/psg/CjhkPw0k/) with this function ``match_results = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".wld")`` completeList  contained is for exemple [D, V, D, V, V, V, V, V] and withthisResult = a value from the list .

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.

Comment: I have modify the code, it is much clearer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem with this code :

```
List_elem = ["D", "V", "D", "D", "D", "V", "D", "V", "V", "V", "V","D","V","V"]
elem_of_list = "D"
valeur = 0
dic_list = {1: valeur}

for numberResult in range(0, len(List_elem)):
       if elem_of_list != List_elem[numberResult]:
         dic_list[len(dic_list)] = valeur = valeur + 1
       elif elem_of_list == List_elem[numberResult] and elem_of_list != List_elem[numberResult-1] and numberResult-1 > - 1:
         dic_list[len(dic_list)+1] = valeur = 0
```

I've just initialised the dictionary `dic_list`with a key = 1 and value associate = 0.
I think that because like the key not exist, `len(dic_list)` return 0 but as I incremate the value associate of the key = 0  so a new key is create and `len(dic_list)` becomes equal to 1, And so on, this create a incremated of the key to every turn and a create of keys.
If someone could confirm and better explain if it is not very clear and that my explanation is good or on the contrary correct. I would like to have your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that I didn't fully understand the whole question, but if I take it as a general question of finding the longest streak of list that don't match certain value, so that can be a nice approach:

```
from itertools import groupby
a = [1,2,3,2,3,4,6,7,2,3,4,2,0,2,2]
ref = 2
m_ans = [len(list(v)) for i,v in groupby(a, lambda x: x!=ref)]
print(max(m_ans))
```

output:

```
4
```

hope that even if this not what you looked for, you will find it as a good kick-start

Comment: Thanks but this is not a general question. I edit my question, I hope it will be more understandable. Sorry if it wasn't clear before I didn't know exactly where the problem came from